# How do I combine a ListPlot and a Magnitude BodePlot

Tags: plotting

I have frequency response data from a lab test.  I can make a ListPlot of the data.  I have theoretical frequency response plotted as a BodePlot. I want to combine (overlay) the lab data on the magnitude BodePlot.  How is that done?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen `Show` or `Overlay`? For more specific answers you will want to include some sample data for people to play with.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two sets of Data therefore two Plots:

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[(s + 0.25)/(s^2 + s + 1), s]
bdP = BodePlot[tfm, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

```
lp2 = LogPlot[x^x, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

and you can combine both Plots with [Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

```
Show[bdP, lp2]
```

[image]

Read carefully: [BodePlot-Details and Options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BodePlot.html#)